# Display the 'commerce_user_orders' view in node

Tags: 7, nodes, commerce, views

I'd like to display the table on the Orders page made by Drupal Commerce on another node along with other content. I believe this table is the `commerce_user_orders` view so I have tried using the following PHP code but all I get is a white screen when I try to view the node. Is there anyway I can overcome this?

```
<?php

$view = views_get_view('commerce_user_orders');
print views_build_view('embed', $view);
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically show a view block?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8369/how-do-i-programmatically-show-a-view-block)

Comment: @AnilSagar I don't think it is. When I try the accepted solution, it doesn't appear to work. The node loads correctly but the view still isn't displayed.